# How to define a structure variable inside another structure?

Tags: c, struct

I have 2 structures defined as follows :

```
typedef struct
{   
    char book_name[20] ;
    int book_id ;
    char author[20] ;
    char book_status[20];
}stlib ;

typedef struct
{
    char employee_name[20];
    int employee_id;
    char employee_dept[20];
    char emp_book_status[20];   
}stemp ;
```

How can I define a variable inside a structure pointing to another structure? Is this correct way ?

```
typedef struct
{   
    char book_name[20] ;
    int book_id ;
    char author[20] ;
    char book_status[20];   
}stlib ;

typedef struct
{
    char employee_name[20];
    int employee_id;
    char employee_dept[20];
    char emp_book_status[20];       
    struct stlib st; // is this correct ?
}stemp ;
```

Answer (score 4):

In your case, as we can see, `stlib` is a `typedef` to the unnamed struct and the definition of `stlib` appears before that of `stemp`, you need to change

```
 struct stlib st; // is this correct ?
```

to

```
stlib st; // this is correct
```

in `stemp` definition and you're good to go.

---

However, if by saying "*inside a structure **pointing** to another structure*", you meant a pointer, then you need to define `st` as a pointer, that's all.